# Laws that Protect Inventions

Tags: patents

I would like to patent something.

What laws are on the books that would protect invention from being stolen

- by patent attorney
- by someone at the US patent office

Please share references

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better asked at https://patents.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a legal question. I am looking for black-and-white answer.

Comment: @Marium only the judge trying your particular case can give you a black-and-white legal answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just doesn’t happen. It is prohibited for a patent examiner to get a patent or any interest in a patent other than by inheritance

> Pursuant to 35 U.S.C. 4, patent examiners, other Office employees, and Office officers may not apply for a patent or acquire any right or interest in any patent during the period of their employment with the Office and for one year thereafter.

and a patent attorney  would lose their USPTO registration and law license at a minimum for violating their [oath](https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/documents/PTO1209_Oath_or_Affirmation.pdf). Very few inventions have the potential to make enough money to risk a career. You will need to trust in the professionalism of many people on the path to making your idea a profitable reality.

Comment: I've heard horror stories that have prevented me from giving it a try (not by professionals though)

Comment: The real horror stories are from people who trusted invention promotion companies -1-800 XXX XXX” places. The problem is not that they steal your great idea but that they tell you your potentially non-novel so-so idea has never been done before and is the best thing they have seen in years. Then you pay $5k and they do not do much for it.